# Creating "districts" from points

Tags: qgis, redistricting

Hypothetical situation: I've got a database with 100,000 customer addresses, which are spread out across the continental US. I've also got a year end totals for number of purchases and value of purchases.

I'd like to take that table and create districts based on sales data. To start with, I'd like as many districts as necessary with roughly 1,000 purchases in each district. I'd like to avoid gerrymandering as much as possible. I'd like to do the same thing per $1,000,000 in sales. I'd also like to be able to generate districts quickly and repeatedly with slightly different parameters (2,000 purchases, $500,000 sales, etc).

I anticipate that areas with higher population density would be composed of smaller districts. I'd use each of these iterations to manually define my own districts based on available personnel, etc.

Here's my problem: I know this can be done, but I'm not even sure which search terms I should be using to find some guidance. I've read up a little on election redistricting, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to make that approach work for me. It's not just where the customer/voter is located, but there are also financial components (such as sales volume), and I don't see those kind of considerations used in creating election districts.

What do you call what I'm trying to do? What tools/procedures/processes should I begin to dig into? I'm prefer a solution using QGIS, but I have the entire OSGeo suite. I do not currently have access to any ArcGIS products.

Comment: You might research PySal. It can perform spatial clustering and many other things. I have not used the tool myself.

Comment: Since the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) states that Questions should, "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced" and the [Asking](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page states "please make an initial effort to research the answer before you ask a question", this question seems to be off-topic here.  GIS SE isn't really intended to serve as a starting point so much as an assist to reaching the end point.  As it stands, I think this question is *too broad* and too complex for the "Focused question/best answer" model used here.

Comment: I agree with @VInce.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: I've definitely got a more specific case I'm working with ... I intentionally generalized the question in order to have a wider audience. Should I rework this question or start a new one?